# ScrollView in the form is not working in android

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have made a simple form in android and have put all the form contents in that scrollView but my scrollView doesnt working ,It not scrolls down,My code is as below:
**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="7dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#4fc1e9" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_reg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/line"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="13dp"
        android:text="@string/title_registration"
        android:textColor="#cecece"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_qq_login"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title_reg" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_qq_login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="#5d9cec"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="@string/qq_login"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_qq_login"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_or"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/or"
                android:textColor="#cecece"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_reg_new_account"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_or"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/reg_new_account"
                android:textColor="#cecece"
                android:textColorLink="#cecece"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_ur_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_reg_new_account"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/reg_name"
                android:textColor="#cecece"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_txt_ur_name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_ur_name"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_editext"
                android:hint="@string/hint_reg_name"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:textColorHint="#cecece"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_ur_email"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/et_txt_ur_name"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/reg_email"
                android:textColor="#cecece"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_txt_ur_email"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_ur_email"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_editext"
                android:hint="@string/hint_reg_email"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:textColorHint="#cecece"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_ur_phone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/et_txt_ur_email"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/reg_phone_number"
                android:textColor="#cecece"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_txt_ur_phone"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_ur_phone"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_editext"
                android:hint="@string/hint_reg_phone_number"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:textColorHint="#cecece"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_ur_password"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/et_txt_ur_phone"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/reg_pwd"
                android:textColor="#cecece"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_txt_ur_password"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_ur_password"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_editext"
                android:hint="@string/hint_reg_pwd"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:textColorHint="#cecece"
                android:textSize="14dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/reg_bottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#f5f7f9"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_register"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_register"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/btn_reg"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_already_member"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_register"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/txt_already_member"
            android:textColor="#babfc3"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_already_login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_register"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_already_member"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="@string/txt_already_login"
            android:textColor="#3a91ea"
            android:textColorLink="#cecece"
            android:textSize="12dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:background="@drawable/qq" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me sort it out..Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you have problem with ScrollView.you need to specify to the scroll view for scrolling.
just add below property in to ScrollView

```
   android:layout_above="@+id/reg_bottom"
```

you need to bind your scroll view.

thanx.